# Plotting a transposed vector for SVM

Tags: vectors, graphing-functions

I need help plotting a set of transposed vectors to build an SVM. My set is:

Positive class:
$[−1$ $3]^T$, $[0$ $2]^T$, $[0$ $1]^T$, $[0$ $0]^T$

Negative class:
$[1$ $5]^T$, $[1$ $6]^T$, $[3$ $3]^T$

I'm not sure how to plot a transposed vectors and am having trouble starting the problem given to me. If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why does the transpose matter? Why can't you plot each item as an ordered pair like $(x,y)$?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but this is the format my professor gave it to me in. So I thought there was some significance to it.